# Is there a way to get part of a column in a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am writing a sudoku solving algorithm and want to get a 3*3 square.
Currently the sudoku is in a dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
Sudoku_Board = [
    [0, 2, 5, 6, 3, 1, 8, 4, 7],
    [6, 1, 8, 5, 0, 4, 2, 9, 3],
    [3, 7, 4, 9, 8, 2, 5, 0, 1],
    [7, 4, 9, 8, 2, 6, 0, 3, 5],
    [8, 5, 2, 4, 1, 0, 9, 7, 6],
    [1, 6, 0, 7, 9, 5, 4, 8, 2],
    [2, 0, 7, 3, 5, 9, 6, 1, 4],
    [4, 9, 1, 0, 6, 7, 3, 5, 8],
    [5, 3, 6, 1, 4, 8, 7, 2, 0]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(Sudoku_Board)
df2 = df.iloc[:,[1,3,4]]
```

I have tried many methods but they all either slice whole column or the actual items inside, never providing a range of items.
Unless there is no option to do this I don't want a different better solution, I am doing this for the sake of learning and this is the solution I decided on.

Comment: Could you share some code and what would the expected output based on your current situation?

Comment: you can use this `df.iloc[:3, :3]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `iloc` function, if df is your dataframe:

```
square = df.iloc[:3, :3]
```

And you can custom the iloc args, if you want the square in the middle:

```
square = df.iloc[3:6, 3:6]
```